# How to return values from struct in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've made a RangeSlider based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5whzc_9eR78. It works fine, but I'd like to get the left and right values from it, how can I do this?

My code:

```
struct RangeSlider: View {

    @State var width: CGFloat = 0
    @State var width1: CGFloat = 20
    @State var totalWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width-60

    let circleSize: CGFloat = 21

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
                    .frame(width: self.totalWidth+2*self.circleSize, height: self.circleSize/3)

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: self.width1-self.width, height: self.circleSize/3)
                    .offset(x: self.width+self.circleSize)

                HStack(spacing: 0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: self.circleSize, height: self.circleSize)
                        .offset(x: self.width)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged({ (value) in
                                    if (value.location.x >= 0 && value.location.x <= self.width1){

                                        self.width = value.location.x

                                    }
                                }))

                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: self.circleSize, height: self.circleSize)
                        .offset(x: self.width1)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged({ (value) in
                                    if (value.location.x <= self.totalWidth-(2*self.circleSize) && value.location.x >= self.width){

                                        self.width1 = value.location.x

                                    }
                                }))
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the `RangeSlider()` inside a ZStack in my ContentView.swift, I'd like to return the left thumb value `width/totalWidth` and the right thumb value `width1/totalWidth` as it's done in Textfield(text: self.$value) to return the text to variable "value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
@Binding var left: CGFloat
@Binding var right: CGFloat
```

And then set them when `width` and `width1` change.  You will need to pass in Bindings when you construct the RangeSlider: e.g. `RangeSlider(left: $left, right: $right)`